# Laravel routing to wrong controller method

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

I have following 2 routes :

Route1:

```
Route::get(config('api.basepath') . '{username}/{hash}/{object_id}', [
    'action' => 'getObject',
    'uses' => 'ObjectController@getObject',
]);
```

and

Route2:

```
Route::get(config('api.basepath') . 'object-boxes/{object_id}/boxes', function () {
    if (Input::get('action') == 'filter') {
        return App::call('App\Http\Controllers\FilterController@getFilteredContents');
    } else {
        return App::call('App\Http\Controllers\ObjectBoxController@show');
    }
});
```

Now,

Route 1 is available with or without Auth middleware, while Route2 is under Auth middleware.

But, In either call, execution control is going to ObjectController@getObject

When I move Route1 below Route2, then everytime the call goes to ObjectBoxController@show.

I tried Preceed but nothing changed.
How should I fix this

Comment: Just for convenience purposes you can define a Route group (or use the existing api route group) with a `"prefix" => config('api.basepath')` instead of doing that awkward concatenation for the api paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define what the variables in the routes are going to be, not the `where` at the end of each route:

```
Route::get(config('api.basepath') . '{username}/{hash}/{object_id}', [
    'action' => 'getObject',
    'uses' => 'ObjectController@getObject',
])->where('object_id', '[0-9]+');

Route::get(config('api.basepath') . 'object-boxes/{object_id}/boxes', function () {
    if (Input::get('action') == 'filter') {
        return App::call('App\Http\Controllers\FilterController@getFilteredContents');
    } else {
        return App::call('App\Http\Controllers\ObjectBoxController@show');
    }
})->where('object_id', '[0-9]+');
```

> You may constrain the format of your route parameters using the where method on a route instance. The where method accepts the name of the parameter and a regular expression defining how the parameter should be constrained:

[Read the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

Comment: Nice! Also keep in mind what [Sagar Gautam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45052395/1336174) posted! This is the main reason your problem exists!

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I have discussed about problem but this is the right way to handle such problem.

Comment: @SagarGautam, true, but you explain *why* it happens, which is also quite important if you want to avoid it next time!

Comment: Great, Cheers :D

Answer (score 4):

Your first and second route are similar,

**First Route**

```
config('api.basepath') . '{username}/{hash}/{object_id}'
```

**Second Route**

```
config('api.basepath') . 'object-boxes/{object_id}/boxes'
```

when you have second route case, it has been treated as former one and takes `username` as `object-boxes` and `object_id` as `boxes`. So same function is called for both cases. So, try with something different route pattern for these two routes.

Comment: Thanks Sagar, I understand the reason.. but the routes are Client provided ones thus needed a solution to differentiate them.

Comment: congrats bro, you have got solution to your problem